# Geo Locator with selenium code for opentest

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, opentest

OpenTest (Selenium code)

How Can I include a GEO location in order to get a different test according with the country?

The page has three option in a country filed, that the test most read option1 if the Country is 1 and option 2 when the country is 2 then just read "Locator" if the user is not in option 1 or 2.

Comment: It's expected that you make an honest effort at trying to figure this out and then show what you've attempted here for input on that.

Comment: hey @AdamWinter did you try to find code for Opentest?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand your scenario, but it sounds like you could use the execution environments feature of OpenTest (more information [here](https://getopentest.org/docs/environments.html)). Just create two different environments for the two countries and store the country code in an environment-specific data file, something like this:

**test-repo/data-env/us/config.yaml**

```
countryCode: US
```

Then, you can use the expression `$data("config").countryCode` to read the country code and perform conditional logic based on that in your tests.